# AngularJS: Best practice displaying static text based on a state/variable

Tags: angularjs

I have small text portions like

```
<div>
    <h4>Why Register?</h4>
    <p>As candidate...</p>
</div>
```

opposed to

```
<div>
    <h4>Why Register?</h4>
    <p>As company...</p>
</div>
```

Based on a variable in my controller I insert the correct partial with:

```
<div ng-switch on="role">
  <div ng-switch-when="candidate">
    <div ng-include="'candidate.html'"></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="company">
    <div ng-include="'company.html'"></div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
    <div ng-include="'candidate.html'"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does the job but it looks awful. Is there any way I could do it better?

Comment: you could use a controller with member and use the "{{}}" to show it

Comment: have you ever heard from routing with angularJs? here's the link to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) And here is my [github](https://github.com/Giwwel/angularRouting) for testing routing with angularJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<div ng-include="(role || 'candidate') + '.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always hold your string vars in javascript or external json file and use markup which is tied to a model like this:

```
<div ng-controller="something">
    <h4>Why Register?</h4>
    <p>{{who}}</p>
</div>
```

and then inside your "something" controller provide code:

```
if(role == "company")
 $scope.who = "As company...";
else
 $Scope.who = "As candidate...";
```

If you have many places in code that use such feature, you could consider holding variables in external json and then reading them in javascript/controller.

Answer (score 0):

If the parts are not that big you can put them all up there and use ng-show to filter which gets actually shown. This takes up the least markup.

```
<h4>Why register?</h4>
<p ng-show="isCompany">Company targeted content...</p>
<p ng-show="isCandidate">Candidate targeted content...</p>
```